# How to correlate Blazor activity for a given circuit or "session"

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

Suppose you have a simple server side Blazor app containing a single web page with one button, e.g.:

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private async Task IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Every time a (GUEST) user clicks the one button, a different thread will handle the request.

Is there a single identifier of the Blazor circuit or "session" which would allow some sort of correlation of the described activity?

Comment: What do you mean `a different thread will handle the request`?

Comment: Exactly the stated - when a user clicks a button, the thread which will handle the request (the button click) will be different for each click, and with it the thread id - but user will not navigate away from the page.

Comment: The 'await' operator is not guaranteed to change the thread, nor allocate a new one, though it way happen based on necessity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have researched the problem and created a sample for server side Blazor: [https://github.com/akovac35/Logging.Samples](https://github.com/akovac35/LoggingSamples)

The main points are the following:

1. Register the relevant middleware which will create an ambient context via AsyncLocal,
2. obtain current correlation from AsyncLocal in custom code or Blazor page,
3. the above also works when Blazor is behind proxy.

The following log excerpt shows how during the same activity thread changes from 8 to 10 while the correlation value fe515ed1-d387-4b95-aef2-79eccc978017 remains the same. Thus we can quickly identify the actual problem by requesting the correlation value from the user and inspecting the logs in case we have an error in the application.

```
[21:40:10.495 +01:00] VRB 8 fe515ed1-d387-4b95-aef2-79eccc978017 <WebApp.Pages.Counter:IncrementCount:25> Entering 
[21:40:10.509 +01:00] INF 8 fe515ed1-d387-4b95-aef2-79eccc978017 <WebApp.Pages.Counter:IncrementCount:28> currentCount: 2 
[21:40:10.595 +01:00] VRB 8 fe515ed1-d387-4b95-aef2-79eccc978017 <Shared.Mocks.BusinessLogicMock`1:FirstLevelAsync:41> Entering: 500 
[21:40:10.691 +01:00] VRB 8 fe515ed1-d387-4b95-aef2-79eccc978017 <Shared.Mocks.BusinessLogicMock`1:SecondLevelAsync:51> Entering: 500 
[21:40:10.776 +01:00] VRB 8 fe515ed1-d387-4b95-aef2-79eccc978017 <Shared.Mocks.BusinessLogicMock`1:ThirdLevelAsync:61> Entering: 500 
[21:40:11.362 +01:00] VRB 10 fe515ed1-d387-4b95-aef2-79eccc978017 <Shared.Mocks.BusinessLogicMock`1:ThirdLevelAsync:65> Exiting: 500 
[21:40:11.378 +01:00] VRB 10 fe515ed1-d387-4b95-aef2-79eccc978017 <Shared.Mocks.BusinessLogicMock`1:SecondLevelAsync:55> Exiting: 500 
[21:40:11.396 +01:00] VRB 10 fe515ed1-d387-4b95-aef2-79eccc978017 <Shared.Mocks.BusinessLogicMock`1:FirstLevelAsync:45> Exiting: 500 
[21:40:11.490 +01:00] VRB 10 fe515ed1-d387-4b95-aef2-79eccc978017 <WebApp.Pages.Counter:IncrementCount:34> Exiting
```

Comment: [Careful using IHttpContextAccessor with blazor server....](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1#blazor-and-shared-state) "you must not use IHttpContextAccessor within Blazor apps. Blazor apps run outside of the context of the ASP.NET Core pipeline and the HttpContext isn't guaranteed to be available within the IHttpContextAccessor, nor it is guaranteed to be holding the context that started the Blazor app."

Comment: OK and no problem, I’m looking into best practices in this area myself. Had a quick look at the code and I’d suggest using [this approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1#pass-tokens-to-a-blazor-server-app) to be safer - this will also mean you’ll have a single trace ID for the life of the app as I understand it and it won’t matter if http context becomes unavailable. The above link talks about a security scenario but it also shows a general approach for passing initial state to a blazor server app.

Comment: Presumably to do what you want with logging you could wrap your logger and inject a service containing the request ID into your wrapper, this injected service could be set up like the token provider in the example above. Also, it seems that not only could the context change [it could be null](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18183).

Comment: I was able to solve the problem without wrapping the logger by simply using AsyncLocal in a custom middleware. This also works when Blazor is behind proxy.